# Hidden links are still clickable on the Android browser

Tags: css, android

I've got a contextual menu that appears when a button is clicked. This menu has some links and after some seconds is hidden again. The problem is that after the menu has disappeared the links are still there. They are not shown but are clickable and the green border appears. And after some seconds they disappear.

I've tryied many ways of hiding the menu: display: none, visibility: hidden, width: 0, height: 0, jquery hide, jquery fadeout...  but none worked. Also hidding the links.

Does anyone have a idea about what's happening? With the rest of the browsers it works without problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Try this:

```
position: absolute;
left: -10000px;
```

Comment: Actually I solved it with a post fadeOut (jQuery method) function:

jQuery("#m1").fadeOut( 'slow' ,function() {
   jQuery("#m1").hide();
   jQuery("#m1").addClass("hidden");
});

Where the class hidden is: 

.hidden {
 display: none;
}

Thanks anyway

Comment: Is it not working without adding the class? It seems unnecessary to use the `hide` method and the `addClass` method in the callback function. They essentially do the same thing (make #m1 have `display: none`).